Which timezones exceed the POSIX-required UT Offset range?
The section on Version 3 of the tzfile format from the man pages for tzfile states that:

... the hours part of its transition times may be signed and range from -167 through 167 instead of the POSIX-required unsigned values from 0 through 24.

However, the List of UTC offsets on wikipedia only lists zones between UTC-12 and UTC+14. The same goes for timezones listed on the List of tz database time zones.

Are there any timezones that have a Universal Time offset greater than 24? When would this ever occur?
Why would support for +/- 167 hours be added in Version 3?
Is this referring to UT Offset listed in the ttinfo entries, or is it referring only to the POSIX.1-2017-style TZ string?


not sure if this is helpful but RFC9636 TZif files should have a value in their utoff field [-89999, 93599] seconds ([-24:59:59, 25:59:59]), see sect. 3.2. That sounds more practical to me than -167 through 167 hours. An offset > 24h might occur if you want to shift a timezone by more than a day. Sounds rare to me but not impossible.

I think you may be conflating two different things. The transition time is not a UTC offset - it's a part of the rule that describes when to switch from DST to standard time, or vice versa. This page describes it better, and gives an example (Israel's time transitions) with a transition time of 26 hours - in context, that 26 means that the time change from standard time to DST occurs at 26 hours after midnight (local time) at the beginning of March’s fourth Thursday.

As you pointed out, there are, at the time of writing, no timezones that have a Universal Time offset greater than 24 hours.  This would occur when a governmental body declares it.  Support for +/- 167 hours was likely added in Version 3 to handle that possibility. Consider that these offsets are specified by governmental decree, so the authors of this standard/code probably imagined that a bureaucrat may want to shift their timezone by nearly 1 week since 167 hours = 6 days and 23 hours.  This is basically referring to both the UT Offset listed in the ttinfo entries, and to the POSIX.1-2017-style TZ string (), as explained in the man pages.
